# Has Unison error on "File name too long"

Tags: sync, unison

I'm using Unison for backup/file replication.
Unison has a problem with long file names - it does not sync files with long names

Error:

```
Failed: Error in querying file information: File name too long
```

Over [here](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/unison-users/message/8400) the developer says about plans to fix that.

Any information weather this has been fixed in specific version?
I've tried 2.40.102 - not fixed.

Comment: How long is your filename and what file systems do you use on each side?

Comment: I've got the same issue. Using ext4 on both sides. I guess the maximum file length also has to do with how file names are encoded. For example, I've got a file of 146 characters long that is causing unison (and ls as well) to fail, so I assume UTF8 is used to encode the file names.

Comment: I just found [this post](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/unison-users/message/10756) that says the maximum file length on ecryptfs-encrypted drives is 143. That is consistent with my findings. I am indeed using encrypted home directories.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved as of Unison 2.45. From the [changelog on the manual page](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html#news):

> Incorporated a patch from Irányossy Knoblauch Artúr to make temp file names fit within 143 characters (to make eCryptFS happy).